Azure Application Gateway Proxied URL Lost on 301 Redirect
I have an Azure App Service hosting an Angular web app at a virtual path. I also have an Azure Application Gateway (AAG) proxying a URL that's preferred over the "azurewebsites.net" domain.
Any time I target the virtual path without a trailing slash in the browser, I get a 301 redirect to the Azure URL with the trailing slash (i.e. "some-app-service.azurewebsites.net/SomeVirtualPath" redirects to "some-app-service.azurewebsites.net/SomeVirtualPath/"). In the case of the AAG, the proxy URL is lost in this redirect (i.e. "some-proxy-domain.net/SomeVirtualPath" redirects to "some-app-service.azurewebsites.net/SomeVirtualPath/").
I've tested the AAG and found that it's providing a X-ORIGINAL-HOST header with the desired domain, but my app service doesn't seem to know how to utilize it. I've even tried adding some bicep to configure authentication's forward proxy, but it doesn't seem to be authentication that's triggering this redirect (also tried X-FORWARDED-HOST per some other documentation).
resource authsettingsV2 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'authsettingsV2'
  kind: 'app'
  parent: appService
  properties: {
    platform: {
      enabled: true
    }
    httpSettings: {
      forwardProxy: {
        convention: 'Custom'
        customHostHeaderName: 'X-ORIGINAL-HOST'
      }
    }
    globalValidation: {
      requireAuthentication: true
      unauthenticatedClientAction: 'AllowAnonymous'
    }
  }
}

Any ideas on what else I can try? My Google-Fu seems to be limited to this point.
In case it helps, here's an abbreviated snippet of the bicep I'm using to create the app service:
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'some-app-service'
  location: location
  identity: {
    // ...
  }
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      appSettings: [
        // ...
      ]
      virtualApplications: [
        {
          virtualPath: '/'
          physicalPath: 'site\\wwwroot'
        }
        {
          virtualPath: '/SomeVirtualPath'
          physicalPath: 'site\\wwwroot\\SomeVirtualPath'
        }
      ]
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: outboundSubnet.id
  }
}

And here's a snippet of the YAML I'm using to deploy to it via my ADO pipeline:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: Client - Deploy
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: AzureRM
    azureSubscription: $(SomeAzureSubscription)
    appType: webApp
    WebAppName: some-app-service
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: some-resource-group
    SlotName: production
    VirtualApplication: SomeVirtualPath
    packageForLinux: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Artifacts

In case web.config rewriting is somehow involved, here's what Angular generates during the build process:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/SomeVirtualPath/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
        <add extension=".html" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>


So the issue is with the trailling slash or also with the fact that it is loosing the appgateway url ?

could you share your app gateway config as well ?

The issue is that not specifying the trailing slash causes a redirect that loses the app gateway URL.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the app gateway config. I'm trying to rule out what I can control. Seeing a 301 redirect from the azurewebsites.net URL suggests that I might be able to do it on my side, even if there's also a way to do it throug the AAG.

have you seen this one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/832147/application-gateway-v1-external-site-redirection-a. you will need access to app gateway

Without application gateway access it's difficult to know what's doing. Which kind of target type is used (backend pool or redirect)?
In case of redirect which options are selected?

I haven't seen the AAG settings personally, but this was enough for me to inform the other team. They've setup some redirects to add the trailing slash, which has resolved the issue.
